# use result string from one table as column names for another query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to trying to simplify the following query :-

```
SELECT id, m_field_id_46 AS Liverpool,m_field_id_47 AS London,m_field_id_48 AS Belfast FROM member_data
```

In a way i can dynamically create the column names

```
SELECT id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('m_field_id_',m_field_id,' AS ',m_field_label) FROM member_fields) as dist FROM member_data
```

However this is not working. Please help

Comment: You want concatenation to be done explicitly in MySQL? Because in php you can do that very easily (if you are writing this query in your php page).

Comment: Hi Shrikant, i need to run this weekly as a view in a MySQL database.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by looking at another answer from stackoverflow: -

```
SET @listStr = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('md.m_field_id_',m_field_id,' AS `',m_field_label,'`') FROM member_fields );
SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT ', @listStr, ' FROM member_data');
PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```